# Response.Redirect to external URL - lost session despite "endResponse" set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, redirect

Somwhere in my ASP.NET MVC 2 application I'm saving some data to session:

```
Session["Blah"] = "Ugaga";
```

And it works great. I can access it in all controllers in all methods. But in one method, I'd like to redirect to external URL, so:

```
return Redirect("http://myexternalurl.com");
```

But when I come back to my application (manually, by typing address in browser) Session["Blah"] is null. Redirect seems to clear session data. So I googled a little and found this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_

I followed the instructions and changed redirect code to:

```
 Response.Redirect("http://myexternalurl.com", false);
```

But the result is the same - session data is lost.

I wonder whether returning a view with something like this would solve the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://myexternalurl.com";
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to me to be a right solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you storing the sesson Id in the cookie or are you passing it over in the URL? If you're storing it in the cookie, check to see if the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie exists before the redirect and after the redirect.

Comment: @Andrzej What is you session state mode?

Comment: @heymega I'm using cookie. It exists all the time, but the sessionID is different after redirect.

Comment: @Andrzej I +1ed because I was having a similar session issue, but not because of Response.Redirect. Your link prompted me to check the max num of worker process on the app pool. Lo and behold it was set to 2 resulting in session loss due to some requests being handled by the other worker process